# Invalid parameter not satisfying: nibNameMap != nil

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I was following a tutorial on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ymz6i07DRM&feature=youtu.be

Ive done exactly what he did. And edited a few things because I'm using the latest Xcode 7.

When i run the application, the emulator opens, and launch screen appears. Immediately after that it goes back to the Xcode with an error in the console saying

> `*** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboard
>   initWithBundle:storyboardFileName:identifierToNibNameMap:identifierToExternalStoryboardReferenceMap:designatedEntryPointIdentifier:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3473.13/UIStoryboard.m:63`
>
> `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not
>   satisfying: nibNameMap != nil'`

Ive tried searching everywhere but I couldn't find a way to get rid of this. Please help if anyone knows how to solve this.

Comment: http://indiestack.com/2015/05/right-storyboard-wrong-platform/

Comment: read this but how to fix it? Didn't quite understand

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see the tutorial you're using involves Storyboards.

Check that you have ticked "Is Initial View Controller" appropriately in the storyboard you're editing.  If this is not checked then I'd expect the error you're seeing.